# Eclipse Scout Neon : service registry does not contain a service of type

Tags: service, eclipse-scout, eclipse-neon

I try to call scout service from Scout Form, so I create interface in shared folder

```
@TunnelToServer
public interface IPersonsFormService extends IService {

  void test();
}
```

and in server I created implementation of this interface

```
public class PersonsFormService implements IPersonsFormService {

  @Override
  public void test() {

    System.out.println("TEST");

  }

}
```

but I get

```
o.e.scout.rt.platform.exception.ExceptionHandler - SecurityException:service registry does not contain a service of type com.sixt.leasing.contract.scout.shared.person.IPersonsFormService [majorPrincipal: 'marko']
java.lang.SecurityException: service registry does not contain a service of type com.sixt.leasing.contract.scout.shared.person.IPersonsFormService
```

It looks like interface is not registered, but in Neon I thought that service is registered with  `@TunnelToServer` annotation.

Where else should I register service ?

This project is extension project of main project.

In Main project all services works,....

Comment: Is everything OK in your POM? My guess is that your Jandex is wrong and this is why your service is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: put `scout.xml` with default content in `src/main/resources/META-INF` folder of the server project.

Why did this happen? Since this is an extension we apparently forgot to copy this file and Scout Neon seems to ignore projects that don't contain this file.

Figured this out by putting a PlatformListener in that project and since that never triggered it was easier to track down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This annotation is requested for Remote-Service (see also the [3.5.1. @TunnelToServer](https://tools.bsiag.com/scoutbook/5.2/latest/book_scout_architecture/scout_architecture/scout_architecture.html#tunneltoserver) section). The implementation class (or the interface) should have the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation.

For Local-Service, use either the `@Bean` or the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation to register the service.

---

If your annotations are correct, your Jandex index might be broken.
Start the application with `-Djandex.rebuild=true` to rebuild the application on startup.

This will recalculate each of your `target/classes/META-INF/jandex.idx` files.

Of course, you can also delete each file manually. Running `mvn clean` also clean those files.

Comment: No, this does not solve my problem. I try to put Bean and  ApplicationScoped on my implementation class but I get same error.