# Eclipse Scout Neon : code type not working

Tags: listbox, lookup, eclipse-scout

I have one `List box` and I would like to set code type of it.

I create new `AbstractCodeType`  :

```
public class MyCodeType extends AbstractCodeType<String, String> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6808664924551155395L;

  public static final String ID = null;

  @Override
  public String getId() {

    return ID;
  }

  @Order(10.0)
  public static class UnknownCode extends AbstractCode<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1307260056726644943L;

    public static final String ID = "Unknown";

    @Override
    protected String getConfiguredText() {

      return TEXTS.get("Unknown");
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {

      return ID;
    }
  }
}
```

and I set this code type in list box :

```
 @Override
  protected Class<? extends ICodeType<?, String>> getConfiguredCodeType() {

    return MyCodeType.class;
  }
```

But doesn't work. It return empty box.

While I was debugging I noticed that in `AbstractListBox.class` in `initConfig` method it call this code type and set code type in `m_lookupCall` inside `setCodeTypeClass`. Then inside `execLoadTableData`, it get `call` but this call return empty array when called `call.getDataByAll()`.

I suspect that converting between code type and Lookup call does not work properly.

EDIT

---

I try to debug where is the problem and if follow the path :

```
initConfig() -> CodeLookupCall.newInstanceByService(m_codeTypeClass); (line 581)
```

and if you look inside `CodeLookupCall` ;

```
getDataByAll() in line 221 `resolveCodes(v)` -> BEANS.opt(m_codeTypeClass) -> bean.getInstance() -> m_producer.produce(this) -> return (T) getCache().get(createCacheKey(type));
```

This is in class CodeService.class in line 97 :

`Class<T>` type is right class and `createCacheKey(type)` return not null object but then `getCache().get(...)` return `null`. From this point on everything is null (what is reasonable regarding that getCodeType return null.)

This is what I found out while debugging, if it helps someone to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code snippet with Eclipse Scout Neon M4 and I could reproduce your described error.

However, it seems that this bug has been fixed with Scout Neon M5. So I suggest that you upgrade to the latest milestone version, which is recommended anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your codetype class is not found by the bean manager. CodeService only finds CodeTypes in its classpath (accessible in the server).

-> You might need to move your class to the shared project.

You can find examples for code types in the contacts demo application:
https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipse.scout.docs/tree/releases/5.2.x/code/contacts

Comment: I have my code type in shared project as in older versions of Scout

Comment: Are you sure your Jandex inventory for that project is up-to-date? See your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673540/eclipse-scout-neon-service-registry-does-not-contain-a-service-of-type